# Working with Charts( BarChartDataEntry) iOS library inObjective C with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, xcode8, ios-charts

I installed the Chart library (version 3.0.1) (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my `objective-C` project. In the previous version of my code, below line works successfully,

```
    BarChartDataSet *set12 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yvals label:@"Water Consumed"];
```

In latest version of charts i.e 3.0.1, the above line results in build error:-

> No visible @interface for 'BarChartDataEntry' declares the selector
>   'initWithValue:xIndex:'

I've `BarChartDataSet` class and there is no such method. What will be the replacement of this method in objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below method for BarChartDataSet

```
BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals label:@"Quarter Share"];
```

Just Replace  `initWithYVals` to  `initWithValues`.

Comment: What will be the alternative of `barSpace` property. Error:- Property 'barSpace' not found on object of type BarChartDataSet.

Comment: I think that was removed from `BarChartDataSet` and added into `BarChartData` please check this link : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1849

Comment: What is the alternative of `[[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets]` ?

Comment: `[[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets]` alternative is `BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];`

Comment: I really appreciate your helping hand to resolve my problem. Can I ask more alternative please. Alternative of `[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:obj.quantity.doubleValue xIndex:i]` ?

Comment: I am happy to help you but its good to ask new question with all your query combine in single question.

use this alternative option method : `[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:index y:yValue]`.

Comment: is your problem solved ? if yes can you accept this answer so other can find it helpful ?

Comment: Please [have a look at new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41892396/988169) which is related to `ios-charts`. I am sure that you can help me to resolve this.