# How to set x-axis on bar chart data - ios-charts?

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

Previously we can set the x-Axis of bar chart data as below:-

`BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xvals dataSets:dataSets];`

In latest updated of `ios-charts` library, the syntax changed to below:-
            `BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];`

How to set the x axis on `BarChartData`?

Comment: What you need to show in XAxis can you tell me ? or provide screenshot what you are trying to achieve so I can get proper idea?

Comment: I come to know that x values will be shown by `IAxisValueFormatter` and its delegate method `stringForValue`. When I tried to use IAxisValueFormatter in my viewController, then I get the error:- `cannot find protocol declaration`.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39149070/988169) shared the approach while working with swift. Can you tell me the same in objective c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of this [Answer (swift version)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762672/988169), I am able to show xAxis string values on bar chart in `Objective-C`.

```
NSMutableArray *xValsDietArray;
```

Set up your chart data. Basic example is as follows:-

```
for (int i=0; i<dietArray.count; i++) {
    DietInput *obj = [dietArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *dateStr = @"Jan";
    [xValsDietArray addObject:dateStr];//Maintain this xValsDietArray. It will be used later on while setting x values. This contains array of x-axis values
    [yvals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]initWithX:[[xValsDietArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] y:obj.calorieInput.doubleValue data:xValsDietArray] ];
}

BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yvals label:@"Water Consumed"];
NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataSets addObject:set1];
BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];
cell.chartView.data=data;
cell.chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self;// Set the delegate to self. THIS IS THE MAIN ADDITION IN NEW CHART LIBRARY
```

Implement the `stringForValue` delegate method as follows:-

```
- (NSString * _Nonnull)stringForValue:(double)value axis:(ChartAxisBase * _Nullable)axis
{
    NSString *xAxisStringValue = @"";
    int myInt = (int)value;

    if(xValsDietArray.count > myInt)
        xAxisStringValue = [xValsDietArray objectAtIndex:myInt];

    return xAxisStringValue;
}
```

Comment: But how can that possible as you are setting value in BarChartDataEntry and while in delegate method you are using as object something is wrong with this i suspect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below same method of `IAxisValueFormatter` with **value** as index and fetch data from xArray and show your custom `X values` in it.

```
#pragma mark - IAxisValueFormatter

- (NSString *)stringForValue:(double)value
                        axis:(ChartAxisBase *)axis
{
    NSString *xValue = [xArray objectAtIndex:value];
    return xValue;
}
```

You can use this as delegate methods of `IAxisValueFormatter`.

Hope this will helps you to set xAxis in your chart.

Comment: I did the exactly same. But value is not treated as index.

Comment: Can you show me your BarChartDataEntry code so its easy to solve your problem ?

Comment: `[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:idx y:yValue];` This one.

Comment: Let continue the [discussion in chat here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134182/bar-chart)